# CXF - exception handling and response with my custom message

Tags: web-services, exception, cxf, jax-ws

I have developed web service using Apache CXF and now I want to deal with exception handling mechanism. Is there any way to configure it like some general listener (aspect, interceptor, whatever...) waiting for any runtime exception. and when it occurs will send my custom ResponseType message to user. This custom message is, it's clear, type from XSD scheme.

Answer (score 1):

It is good to define fault for each operation you expose. Avoid throwing run time exception instead handle it in service itself.